# Issue while trying to select record in mysql using Python

Tags: python, mysql

**Error Message**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '%s' at line 1

**MySQL Database Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblorders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` date NOT NULL,
  `order_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `tblorders`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `order_number` (`order_number`);

ALTER TABLE `tblorders`
  MODIFY `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

**Code**

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "", database = "mydb")
        
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "Select order_id from tblorders where order_number=%s"        
val = ("1221212")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: There's nothing that tries to insert anything, it just selects.

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) calls out the detail of carefully appending a `,` comma to a 1-tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a list or a tuple as the arguments, but a tuple of a single value is just a scalar in parentheses.

Here are some workarounds to ensure that `val` is interpreted as a tuple or a list:

```
sql = "Select order_id from tblorders where order_number=%s"        
val = ("1221212",)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)

sql = "Select order_id from tblorders where order_number=%s"        
val = ["1221212"]
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

This is a thing about Python that I always find weird, but it makes a kind of sense.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to insert data you have to modify your **SQL**. Use `INSERT` instead of `SELECT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblorders (order_number) VALUES ("122121");
```

That statement will add new record to the table. Besides, in MariaDB you need to use **?** instead of **%s** that works on Mysql database.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tblorders (order_number) VALUES (?);"
val = "1231231"
mycursor.execute(sql, [val])
```